# Odds of winning 2 of next 3, given 60% odds of winning each game

Tags: probability

Lets say I play a best out of 3 match.  First to win 2 wins.

I am better than my opponent and I have 60% chances of winning any match.

Doing the enumeration of all possibilities I have figure out my odds of winning at least 2 are 64.8%.

What is the formula I should have used to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Binomial Formula, because each trial is an independent trial where the probabilities p and q remain unchanged. As you inidacted p = 0.6 so q = 0.4 
You then need to calculate P(X=2) where X = # games won. Realize that there are different ways to reach victory:
Win-Win, 
Lose-Win-Win, 
Win-Lose-Win.

These are three independent calculations. Add your answers

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you did something like $$0.6\times 0.6 + 0.6 \times 0.4 \times 0.6 + 0.4 \times 0.6 \times 0.6.$$

A more general binomial formula where the competition is "best of $2n+1$" independent games where your probability of winning a game is $p$ would be $$\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n+1} {2n+1 \choose i} p^{i}(1-p)^{2n+1-i}.$$

Comment: Thanks, is there a FAQ where I can see the meaning of the formula your gave me

Comment: There is always Wikipedia's [list of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols) but here $\displaystyle\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n+1}$ is the [sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum#Notation) over $i$ running from $n+1$ to $2n+1$ of what follows, while  ${2n+1 \choose i}$ is a [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) or [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) symbol